# MS SQL Server 2012 Auto-Increment & Primary/Foreign Keys

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to see if the Primary/Foreign keys can be used in the following way in MS SQL server 2012.

If I have two `tables` one with employer information and one with recruiter information.

If any given employer can have up to 5 recruiter accounts, then in my table each time a new recruiter account is created with the employer's PK ID in a matching column on the Recruiters table and have a matching field on the recruiters table that has a count of the # of recruiter accounts that exist in the recruiters table.

So

Employers Table = A

```
EmployerID  int Unchecked
UserID  int Checked
AccountStatus   varchar(50) Checked
CompanyName varchar(150)    Checked
JobsPosted  int Checked
ResumeViews int Checked
ResumeFavorites int Checked
Recruiters  int Checked
```

Recruiters Table = B

```
RecruiterID int Unchecked
EmployerID  int Checked
UserID  int Checked
AccountStatus   varchar(50) Checked
JobsPosted  int Checked
ResumeViews int Checked
ResumeFavorites int Checked
```

For each Recruiter that exists in table B auto-increment the value in Table A's `Recruiters` field.

Is that proper use of primary/foreign keys? Or should I be using TSQL to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the point of normalizing your database.

Let your employer data in the Employee  and Recruiter data in the Recruiter and a EmployerRecruiterAccount table where 1 employer can have 5 recruiters.

So your EmployerRecruiterAccount will have EmployeeID and RecruiterID as foreign keys.

Comment: so PK&FK relationships are simply so 1 does not have to repeat in my example `EmployerID` in both tables?

Comment: EMPID and RecruiterID will repeat in your EmployerRecruiterTable and will be controlled by an autoincrement primary key.

Comment: EMPloyerTable will not repeat EMPID , RecruiterTable will not repeat RecruiterID these are you PKs.